# Orphaned AWS s3 Bucket Cannot Be Deleted

Tags: amazon-s3

After making some changes for an aws hosted static website, I deleted an aws s3 bucket through the AWS console. However, the bucket is now orphaned. Although it is not listed in the AWS console, I can see still reach what is left of it through the CLI and through the URI.

When I try to recreate a www bucket with the same name, the AWS console returns the following error:

```
Bucket already exists
```

The bucket with issues has a www prefix, so now I have two different versions (www and non-www) of the same website.

The problem URI is:

```
www.michaelrieder.com and www.michaelrieder.com.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
```

I made many failed attempts to delete the bucket using the aws s3 CLI utility. I tried aws rb force, aws rm, and any other command I remotely thought might work.

I need to delete and recreate the bucket with exactly the same name so I can have www website redirection working correctly as aws enforces static website naming conventions strictly.

When I execute the aws s3 CLI command for example:

```
aws s3 rb s3://www.michaelrieder.com --force --debug
```

A typical CLI error message is:

```
 An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the DeleteObject operation: Access Denied
```

It thought it might be a cache related issue and that the the bucket would flush itself after a period of time, but the issue has persisted for over 48 hours.

It seems to be a permissions issue, but I cannot find a way to change the phantom bucket’s permissions or any method of deleting the bucket or even it’s individual objects, since I do not have access to the bucket via the AWS console or the aws s3 CLI.

Appreciate any ideas. Please help.

Comment: [**Important** *If you want to continue to use the same bucket name, don't delete the bucket.*](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/delete-bucket.html)  It's not clear how the bucket can still be there, but clearly, it is.  I'd speculate that deleting a non-empty bucket from the console is an asynchronous/background process, since it is otherwise impossible to delete a non-empty bucket without purging all the objects first.

Comment: Note also that your bucket is configured quite insecurely, allowing a number of things to be viewed publicly, including the ACL [here](http://www.michaelrieder.com.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/?acl).  Confirm that the account name shown at that link matches the name of the AWS account you are currently using?

Comment: @michael-sqlbot thanks a ton. It is correct the display name/ID of the phantom bucket and the account I am using are not the same. Perhaps because I am setting up the website and the website owner account is doing the billing. For some strange reason AWS has mangled the two accounts and associated the wrong display name/ID with the bucket. (I am the only person working on the site.)  Perhaps if I could somehow change the phantom bucket credentials the bucket would appear in the AWS console, and everything would be normal again. I am perplexed how this might be done?

Comment: I'm reasonably sure AWS has not mangled the account association for the bucket.  But something has changed... the bucket is now in us-west-2 and no longer as public as before.